# MDX Query STRTOSET CONSTRAINED flag

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

I'm not familiar with the MDX language and I got a problem with a Dataset (DataBatchProcessData), this is the MDX query :

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Germ1 Delta Temp In Out Inf]
     ,[Measures].[Germ2 Delta Temp In Out Sup]
     ,[Measures].[Germ2 Delta Temp In Out Inf]
     ,[Measures].[Germ1 Delta Temp In Out Sup]
     ,[Measures].[Germ Nb Sprays]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [65 Batch Process Data].[Batch Number].[Batch Number].ALLMEMBERS*
        [01 Plants].[Plant Name].[Plant Name].ALLMEMBERS*
        [04 Production Units].[Production Unit].[Production Unit].ALLMEMBERS*
        [65 Batch Process Data].[Steeping Start Date].[Steeping Start Date].ALLMEMBERS
    }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    StrToSet
    ("{[65 Batch Process Data].[Batch Number].&[1320165073],[65 Batch Process Data].[Batch Number].&[1320165074],[65 Batch Process Data].[Batch Number].&[1320165075]}"
     ,CONSTRAINED
    ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      StrToSet
      ("[04 Production Unit].[Production Unit].&[1]"
       ,CONSTRAINED
      ) ON COLUMNS
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        StrToSet
        ("[01 Plants].[Plant Name].&[Rostock]"
         ,CONSTRAINED
        ) ON COLUMNS
      FROM [Supervision]
    )
  )
)
CELL PROPERTIES 
  VALUE
 ,BACK_COLOR
 ,FORE_COLOR
 ,FORMATTED_VALUE
 ,FORMAT_STRING
 ,FONT_NAME
 ,FONT_SIZE
 ,FONT_FLAGS;
```

This MDX Query was autogenerated by SSRS, but is not working, I got this error when running my report:

```
Query (8, 9) The restrictions imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag in the STRTOSET function were violated.
```

I got another DataSet (DataGermination) that is quite similar to this Dataset, and it take the same parameters (not in the same dimension tho) :

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Air Temperature Out - Fact Germination Continue]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [81 Germination Continue].[Batch Number].[Batch Number].ALLMEMBERS*
        [80 Germination General].[Plant Name].[Plant Name].ALLMEMBERS*
        [80 Germination General].[Production Unit].[Production Unit].ALLMEMBERS*
        [81 Germination Continue].[Characteristic Date].[Characteristic Date].ALLMEMBERS*
        [80 Germination General].[Start Date  Unloading].[Start Date  Unloading].ALLMEMBERS*
        [80 Germination General].[Start Date].[Start Date].ALLMEMBERS*
        [80 Germination General].[End Date].[End Date].ALLMEMBERS
    }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    StrToSet
    ("[80 Germination General].[Production Unit].&[1]"
     ,CONSTRAINED
    ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      StrToSet
      ("[80 Germination General].[Plant Name].&[Rostock]"
       ,CONSTRAINED
      ) ON COLUMNS
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        StrToSet
        ("{[81 Germination Continue].[Batch Number].&[1320165073],[81 Germination Continue].[Batch Number].&[1320165074],[81 Germination Continue].[Batch Number].&[1320165075]}"
         ,CONSTRAINED
        ) ON COLUMNS
      FROM [Supervision]
    )
  )
)
CELL PROPERTIES 
  VALUE
 ,BACK_COLOR
 ,FORE_COLOR
 ,FORMATTED_VALUE
 ,FORMAT_STRING
 ,FONT_NAME
 ,FONT_SIZE
 ,FONT_FLAGS;
```

When I run these query in SSMS, the 2nd one is working (DataGermination), but I don't know why, the dataset DataBatchProcessData is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From BOL:

> When the CONSTRAINED flag is used, the set specification must contain
>   qualified or unqualified member names or a set of tuples containing
>   qualified or unqualified member names enclosed by braces {}. This flag
>   is used to reduce the risk of injection attacks via the specified
>   string. If a string is provided that is not directly resolvable to
>   qualified or unqualified member names, the following error appears:
>   "The restrictions imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag in the STRTOSET
>   function were violated.

Looks like you are not using the fully qualified member name for the attributes.

It needs to be

```
Dimension Name.Hierarchy Name.Level Name.Member Name
```

or

```
Dimension Name.Hierarchy Name.Level Name.&[Member Value]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect one of the members you've specified does not exist in the cube.

Easy to test.

If you add the folllowing to a very very simple`mdx` script does it run?

```
{[65 Batch Process Data].[Batch Number].&[1320165073]
,[65 Batch Process Data].[Batch Number].&[1320165074]
,[65 Batch Process Data].[Batch Number].&[1320165075]}
```

Just the following should shed light on whether it recognizes these members:

```
SELECT 
  {} ON ROWS
 ,{
    [81 Germination Continue].[Batch Number].&[1320165073]
   ,[81 Germination Continue].[Batch Number].&[1320165074]
   ,[81 Germination Continue].[Batch Number].&[1320165075]
  } ON COLUMNS
FROM [Supervision];
```

Answer (score 0):

You were right SouravA, my problem was for the Batch Number.

It is expecting something like `[65 Batch Process Data].[Batch Number].&[Batch Number]&[Plant Code]&[Production Unit]`

While I was giving him `[65 Batch Process Data].[Batch Number].&[Batch Number]`

Thank you for your help!